# Loading ID3 tags without loading sound in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, flash-cs4, id3

Is there a way to load ID3 tags in AS3 without loading sound?

Answer (score 2):

well you can simply start loading the sound, with [bufferTime](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/SoundLoaderContext.html#bufferTime) = 0, and when the id3 data is available, you just [close](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Sound.html#close%28%29) the stream.

or, if the sound is distributed through a server, then the server could read out the ID3 and provide an API to get it.

Comment: hmm ok. Im going to try that out, and ill let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well using AS3 to read the ID3 Tags is probably not the way to go. You can of course use PHP, C#, Python or any other language to read the ID3 tags out of an MP3.

For instance you can have a PHP Script "id3Reader.php?file=mymp3.php" and will return an XML containing all the ID3 info, then you can parse that in AS3 which is rather quick. I recommend using caching in the PHP part or probably having a data store like mysql so you don't have to be reading the id3 tag over an over. Although PHP is a rotten language it does its job and for this kind of task it does it well.

Reading ID3 with PHP

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.id3.php